# Existence of solutions to n-dimensional integral equation with solutions into [0,1]

Tags: integral-operators

I have a research problem I am working on where a step involves proving the existence of solutions to a certain kind of integral equation. A statement of this problem is as below. I would appreciate any pointers to relevant literature or hints that might be helpful in attempting to devise a proof.

I would like to understand under conditions will there exist an integer $n$ and $n$ functions $g_i(t):[0,1]\mapsto [0,1]$ and $n$ non-negative weights $\gamma_i$, $\sum^n_i \gamma_i=1$, such that, for all $x\in [0,1]$, and for a function $\lambda(x,y):[0,1]\times [0,1] \mapsto [0,1]$ and for fraction $\lambda_0\in [0,1]$:
\begin{equation}\label{equation1}
    \lambda_0 = \sum^n_i \gamma_i \left(\int^x_0 g_i(s)ds + (1-x) \lambda\left(x,\frac{1}{x}\int^x_0 g_i(s)ds\right) \right)
    \end{equation}
We have the following assumptions on $\lambda(x,y)$:

1. $\lambda$ is continuous in both arguments, and smooth in the
   first argument. $\lambda$ is smooth almost everywhere in the second
   argument (there are a finite number of `jumps' in derivative).
2. For all $x$, there exist $y$ such that $\lambda(x,y) = \lambda_0$.
3. For all $y$, $\lambda(0,y) = \lambda_0$.

This is a special case of an n-dimensional implicit integral functional equation, and could be a case of applying, for e.g. (other papers also exist):

```
    https://www.scielo.br/j/tema/a/bN3gNLcV8zDq3PKT8mmNdLh/?lang=en&format=pdf
```

However, the complication is that we require that solutions $g_i(t)$ be into $[0,1]$. As an additional complication, so far numerical simulations show the existence of cases where $n=1$ does not work given the into $[0,1]$ requirement, but where $n> 1$ does work. Note that I am free to choose $n$, so if there is a proof that shows a sufficiently high $n$ works, that would suffice.